# Thunderbird's Unity Icon keeps showing unread mail indication even if there is no unread mail

Tags: unity, thunderbird

[image: Thunderbird's Unity icon]  Thunderbird icon like this which indicate a unread email, keeps on displaying emails as unread even when the new mails have been read and are no longer 'unread'. Any known issues?

Comment: [This question is a bug report, thanks!](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/850229)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is already a bug report in Launchpad with Thunderbird indicator and icon messages count and you can take a look at it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/850229).